# How to make SnackBar NOT match_parent - android kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-snackbar

Initially, I wanted to make `Toast` with a custom layout, but then I saw that starting from `Android 11`, it was not desirable to do this, and the `setView()` method for `Toast` became `deprecated`. I decided to try to do the same, but only for the `Snackbar`.

my xml code for my custom `Snackbar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/blue"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:contentPaddingBottom="4dp"
    app:contentPaddingLeft="12dp"
    app:contentPaddingRight="12dp"
    app:contentPaddingTop="4dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/text_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_vector_check_mark_white"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/tt_hoves_medium"
        android:text="Copied"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

`Kotlin` function for show `SnackBar`:

```
private fun showSnack() {
    val snackbar = Snackbar.make(binding.root, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
    snackbar.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        
    val customSnackView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.component_toast_message, null)
        
    val snackbarLayout = snackbar.view as Snackbar.SnackbarLayout
        
    snackbarLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
    snackbarLayout.addView(customSnackView)
    snackbar.show()
}
```

However, I ran into a problem that my `Snackbar` has a `match_parant` width, although I need it to have the size of the `View` itself, that is, `wrap_content`, but using various methods I could not achieve this. Is there any solution for this?

How it looks on my phone:
[image]

How it should look like:
[image]

Comment: I think Toast is more proper than Snackbar

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try Toast. Much simpler and match your requirement.

If you still want to make your SnackBar not matching parent you could try adding layoutParams programatically like this:

`val layoutParams = snackbarLayout.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`

`layoutParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`

`snackbarLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams`

I hope it work!